# NodeJS: client.emit('message') needs delay after connection in order to be seen

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm using `socket.io` in a Node application. Here is a snippet from my code:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', socket => {

    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('a client connected!')
        clients.forEach(s => s.emit('to_client', 'a client connected'))
    }, 0)
})
```

If I remove the `setTimeout` wrapper, `'a client connected'` is not seen in the console of the client (Chrome browser), however, even with a timeout of zero, it does show up. What could be the issue? I would prefer going without the `setTimeout` since it does not sound like something that should be required here.

Comment: We need to see the relevant client side code and we need to see how the `clients` variable is maintained.  It could either be that your client event handler is not attached soon enough of that the `clients` variable is not yet updated with the newly connected socket.

Comment: FYI, you can do `io.emit()` from your server and socket.io will broadcast to all connected clients for you.  You don't have to keep track of them all or send to them all yourself.

Comment: Even if the client variable is not updated quickly, server side code should run independent of it. I think I would just use setTimeout. +1 for the io.emit().

Comment: It would be best to understand what is actually happening here rather than just throw in a work-around like `setTimeout()` without understanding what exactly is going on. We can help you understand it if you show us the code I asked for.  Server-side code does run independently of the client code, but there still could be timing issues between the two. If you send a message to the client BEFORE it registers an event handler for that message, the client will miss the message. If this timing issue is racy (varies from one time to the next), then your `setTimeout()` might not be a reliable fix.

Comment: Problems should be worked-around only when they are fully understood.  Throwing in a random `setTimeout()` because it seems to fix the problem is a bad way to write code.  You must understand what causes the timing issue entirely and then and only then will you know what fix will be reliable.  This is one difference between good and bad software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node is an asynchronous single threaded run-time so it uses callbacks to avoid blocking the I/O.

Using the [setTimeout](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_settimeout_callback_delay_args) is one way (along with nodes built in [process.nextTick()](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_nexttick_callback_args]) method for handling asynchronous code!). Your example code is trying to access `clients`, I suspect whatever is handling this has not been initialised before your connection callback has executed.

The [setTimeout](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_settimeout_callback_delay_args) method basically pushes the code (callback function) onto the event queue and therefore anything currently on the call stack will be processed *before* this setTimeout callback can be run.

Comment: I get it! So basically, it's fine to have a timeout of zero right? Is it OK to approach it like this? I don't think there would be any event that can tell me the array has been initialized.

Comment: @Cosmonavt yes, this is a very common approach! It would however be helpful to see the `clients` code to determine the proper control flow.